# Bluetooth Scanning

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

There is something called Class of Devices(COD) which categorises different bluetooth enabled devices. For example iPhones, Wearable wrist watches etc are placed in separate category and are identified through different hexadecimal codes.

Go through this link:- http://www.question-defense.com/tools/class-of-device-bluetooth-cod-list-in-binary-and-hex

My Question here is that how can I initiate a BLE scan from my iOS App so that it searches for only the device corresponding to a particular COD code.
I am using a normal Core Bluetooth approach for scanning the devices that is through Service ID and all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not exposed by the Core Bluetooth APIs and there is no API you can use to scan based on COD code. You can only scan for GATT services using the Core Bluetooth Framework